# Вопрос по html/css. Как сверстать две панели навигации в разных блоках

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сверстать две панели навигации в разных блоках. Как на скрине. При планшетном разрешении скрывалась в бургер нижняя. В мобильной обе[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предоставьте код, ваши варианты решения.

Comment: Предоставьте код, что вы пытались сделать? что не получилось? Сверстать просто (block, flex, grid), но это не тот ресурс где за вас по картинке будут верстать

Answer (score 0):

1. Верстаете верхний блок;
2. Верстаете нижний блок;
3. Сверстайте блок бургер меню под "основным меню" и задайте ему display: none, чтобы его скрыть. Чисто для примера:

```
<header class="header-2">
 <a href="#" class="sub-menu-item">Item</a>
   <a href="#" class="sub-menu-item">Item</a>
 <a href="#" class="sub-menu-item">Item</a>
</header>
<div class="burger"></div>
```

4. задайте медиа выражение, которое скроет осноное меню навигации и покажет бургер. Для примера для нижнего блока

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-2 {
display: none;
}
.burger {
display: block;
}
}
```

5. Сделайте аналогичное медиа-выражение для двух блоков при рамере экрана для моб устройств.